# Get the right number of the current row (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to create a "like" button in my project. To detect current row *(where the clicked button is)* in UITableViewCell i'm using the following code:

```
-(void)likeBtnClick:(id)sender {
    UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"current Row=%d",senderButton.tag);
}
```

So, for the first cell NSLog shows

"current Row=203", for the second – "current Row=200", for the third – "current Row=197". **But** for the 4th row it is "current Row=203" **again** (5th – "current Row=200", 6th – "current Row=197", etc)!

And the same error repeats every 3 rows.

My question is - how to get the **right number** of the current row in UITableView?

**UPDATE:**

For Lyndsey Scott – cellForRowAtIndexPath method code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"NewsCell"];
    }
    [self.tableView setScrollsToTop:YES];
    [HUD hide:YES];
    Location *location = [_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIButton *lkbut = (UIButton*) [cell viewWithTag:300];
    [lkbut setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"likehq2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSInteger value = [location.information intValue];

    NSLog(@"val %ld", (long)value);

    lkbut.tag = value;
    NSLog(@"ur %@", location.user_like);
    [lkbut addTarget:self action:@selector(likeBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //...
    return cell;
}
```

***Solution:***

```
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    NSLog(@"indexPath.row = %ld", (long)indexPath.row);

    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[_locations count] - (long)indexPath.row);
```

"(unsigned long)[_locations count]" - is a number of your rows. //everyone has own code here

*Thanks Anna, Lyndsey Scott and JOM!*

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1802875/467105 for a better approach than tags.

Comment: I'v seen it, but the number like "0x00000016" is not what I need

Comment: How do you see that text?  How are you logging the resulting indexPath?  Did you try `NSLog(@"indexPath.row = %d", indexPath.row);`?

Comment: Could you post the code from your cellForRowAtIndexPath method where you're setting the tags?

Comment: "-(void)likeBtnClick:(id)sender" is not in "-(UITableViewCell *)tableView", so indexPath is not declared there...

Comment: Lyndsey Scott, see topic update

Comment: @dvijok follow Anna's comment! thats the correct approach. Tags are very unreliable in this scenario.

Comment: Seems like there's an issue with your location "information" values.

Comment: Actually, I think I know what's going on... Your buttons are being reused.

Comment: Using Anna's approach I've got the following in console: <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000018016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3} But how can get only "3" (or 2, 1, 0) from "path = 0 - 3"?

Comment: @dvijok, Look at the sample NSLog in my second comment.  Don't log the whole indexPath object using `%@`.  Use `indexPath.row` and `%d`.  Using the `indexPath.row`, you can then get the data directly from your data source (`[_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`).

Comment: I seriously dislike running into code that uses obscure tags, it's bad coding habits. A much better concept would be to use a delegate callback (or a block callback). If you configure the cell with a block callback, just return the cell in the callback and you can use. Just configure the below in cell for row at index path:

    [cell configureWithStuff:(id)stuff withSelection:^(UITableViewCell *cell, BOOL selected) {
     NSIndexPath *index = [tableview indexPathForCell:cell];
    }

 At that point, your code is very direct, precise, predictable, and not obscured.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get same number again, is that tableview cells are being recycled. In your case it seems like there's max 3 rows on-screen at a time.

Anyway, here's my answer for similar question earlier: [iPhone - How to determine in which cell a button was pressed in a custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029707/iphone-how-to-determine-in-which-cell-a-button-was-pressed-in-a-custom-uitable/2093280#2093280)

Update: Anna has a good suggestion, which should work, too. Please check it out and see, it if works better.

Third way might be that you **reset cell tag with indexPath.row**, when you create/recycle a cell. There's always more than one way to do anything ;)

Comment: Need to be careful with this superview method since the view hierarchy is different depending on iOS version.

Comment: Yeah, I don't agree with the method, but the assessment is right...

Comment: When I use this code, I get value from 0. But I have about 200 cells (or more). So how can I get values from highest to lowest?

Comment: @dvijok Don't use this code. Use Anna's method. Just note that the reason your tags aren't working is because: "The reason you get same number again, is that tableview cells are being recycled. In your case it seems like there's max 3 rows on-screen at a time."

Comment: Ok, I've understood how to use Anna's method just now... :)

But I still have the same question: "When I use this code, I get value from 0. But I have about 200 cells (or more). So how can I get values from highest to lowest?"

Comment: Oh. I have a solution. If someone needs... NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[_locations count] - (long)indexPath.row); can help you. "(unsigned long)[_locations count]" - is a number of your rows.

Comment: BTW, thanks Anna, Lyndsey Scott and JOM! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this:

Firstly:

```
[lkbut addTarget:self action:@selector(likeBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

should be:

```
[lkbut addTarget:self action:@selector(likeBtnClick:andEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and your `button` action methods should be:

```
-(void)likeBtnClick:(id)sender andEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:currentTouchPosition];

    NSLog(@"current Row=%d",indexPath.row);
}
```

---

Basically, no need to go through all that tag muck.

Comment: No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares he selector 'indexPathForItemAtPoint:'...

Comment: @dvijok : whoops, sorry. `-indexPathForItemAtPoint:` is for a `collectionView`. for `tableView` it should be `-indexPathForRowAtPoint:` ...updated answer